# Use PowerShell to edit a remote file on a Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

Editing a file on a remote linux server via SSH and vim is something I usually do on a regular basis. Recently, I got on a new web project involving Microsoft technologies instead of the usual open source.

In a Microsoft environment, PowerShell seems like a quite efficient replacement for bash. It can connect on remote servers using the Enter-PSSession commmand. Unfortunately, it seems that this way of working is incompatible with text editors. Trying to open vim or edit is causing my remote session to hang everytime. I seems it reacts the same on every full screen shell app.

Is there a way to work around this else than installing SSH on Microsoft servers? It would be an awesome solution but I doubt that the technical staff will approve it in the long run since it's not built in the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There isn't really a "good" way to do this the way you seem to want](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3432770/1668244) (short of installing an SSH server).

Two [barely] tolerable options are:

1. To open the file over a UNC share (even the default "admin" share, if you have access to it: `\\servername\driveletter$\restofthepath\file`)
2. To copy the file to the local machine, edit it, and then push it back to the remote server, overwriting the old version.

Comment: I think that mounting a share is my favorite option... haven't thought about that. Thanks!